# Label with variable not updating when event is called in python tkinter

Tags: python, variables, tkinter, label

So I am trying to each time you click one of the buttons that doesn't have the bomb, for the variable "score" to update and immediately being displayed on the bottom. But when I click one of them, the displayed variable is not updated for some reason even though I explicitly said for the "Label" being displayed to have the "text=score". I know my code is quite long and not really efficient but I am a bit new to python and I'm still learning. What could I fix in my code to solve this issue? ANY help is appreciated!

```
from tkinter import *
import random

screen = Tk()

ticket = random.randint(1,3)

score = 0

def test():

    ticket1 = random.randint(1,3)
    ticket2 = random.randint(1,3)

    def test1():
        if ticket1 == button1:
            button_1 = Button(screen, text="RIP", fg="white", bg="red", width=15, height=2)
            button_1.grid(row=1, column=0, sticky="w")
        else:
            button_2 = Button(screen, text="+1", fg="white", bg="green", width=15, height=2)
            button_2.grid(row=1, column=0, sticky="w")
            global score
            score += 1
    def test2():
        if ticket1 == button2:
            button_3 = Button(screen, text="RIP", fg="white", bg="red", width=15, height=2)
            button_3.grid(row=1, column=1, sticky="w")
        else:
            button_4 = Button(screen, text="+1", fg="white", bg="green", width=15, height=2)
            button_4.grid(row=1, column=1, sticky="w")
            global score
            score += 1
    def test3():
        if ticket1 == button3:
            button_5 = Button(screen, text="RIP", fg="white", bg="red", width=15, height=2)
            button_5.grid(row=1, column=2, sticky="w")
        else:
            button_6 = Button(screen, text="+1", fg="white", bg="green", width=15, height=2)
            button_6.grid(row=1, column=2, sticky="w")
            global score
            score += 1
    def test4():
        if ticket2 == button1:
            button_1 = Button(screen, text="RIP", fg="white", bg="red", width=15, height=2)
            button_1.grid(row=0, column=0, sticky="w")
        else:
            button_2 = Button(screen, text="+2", fg="white", bg="green", width=15, height=2)
            button_2.grid(row=0, column=0, sticky="w")
            global score
            score += 2
    def test5():
        if ticket2 == button2:
            button_3 = Button(screen, text="RIP", fg="white", bg="red", width=15, height=2)
            button_3.grid(row=0, column=1, sticky="w")
        else:
            button_4 = Button(screen, text="+2", fg="white", bg="green", width=15, height=2)
            button_4.grid(row=0, column=1, sticky="w")
            global score
            score += 2
    def test6():
        if ticket2 == button3:
            button_5 = Button(screen, text="RIP", fg="white", bg="red", width=15, height=2)
            button_5.grid(row=0, column=2, sticky="w")
        else:
            button_6 = Button(screen, text="+2", fg="white", bg="green", width=15, height=2)
            button_6.grid(row=0, column=2, sticky="w")
            global score
            score += 2

    button1 = Button(screen, text="1", fg="white", bg="blue", width=15, height=2, command=test1)
    button1.grid(row=1, column=0, sticky="w")
    button1 = 1

    button2 = Button(screen, text="2", fg="white", bg="blue", width=15, height=2, command=test2)
    button2.grid(row=1, column=1, sticky="w"+"e"+"n"+"s")
    button2 = 2

    button3 = Button(screen, text="3", fg="white", bg="blue", width=15, height=2, command=test3)
    button3.grid(row=1, column=2, sticky="e")
    button3 = 3

    button4 = Button(screen, text="1", fg="white", bg="blue", width=15, height=2, command=test4)
    button4.grid(row=0, column=0, sticky="w")
    button4 = 1

    button5 = Button(screen, text="2", fg="white", bg="blue", width=15, height=2, command=test5)
    button5.grid(row=0, column=1, sticky="w"+"e"+"n"+"s")
    button5 = 2

    button6 = Button(screen, text="3", fg="white", bg="blue", width=15, height=2, command=test6)
    button6.grid(row=0, column=2, sticky="e")
    button6 = 3

button1 = Button(screen, text="START", fg="black", bg="orange", width=25, height=2, command=test)
button1.grid(row=8, columnspan=3, sticky="w"+"e"+"n"+"s")

scoreText = Label(screen, text="Score: " + str(score), width=25, height=2)
scoreText.grid(row=9, columnspan=3, sticky="w"+"e"+"n"+"s")

screen.mainloop()
```

Comment: instead of `text=`  use `textvariable=` with `tk.StringVar()`  or update directly `scoreText['text'] = "new text"`

Comment: to make code more readable put `global` at the beginning of functions, and add empty space before `def`

Comment: BTW: better change text in buttons `button_1['text'] = "new text"` instead of creating new buttons. Now you may have many buttons in one cell - one button above another.

Answer (score 1):

After you change `score` you have to replace text in label

```
 score += 1
 scoreText['text'] = "Score: " + str(score)
```

Full code which replaces text in buttons instead of creating new ones.

```
import tkinter as tk
import random

def test():

    def test1():
        global score

        if ticket1 == 1:
            button1.config(text="RIP", bg="red")
        else:
            button1.config(text="+1", bg="green")
            score += 1
            label_score['text'] = "Score: " + str(score)

    def test2():
        global score

        if ticket1 == 2:
            button2.config(text="RIP", bg="red")
        else:
            button2.config(text="+1", bg="green")
            score += 1
            label_score['text'] = "Score: " + str(score)

    def test3():
        global score

        if ticket1 == 3:
            button3.config(text="RIP", bg="red")
        else:
            button3.config(text="+1", bg="green")
            score += 1
            label_score['text'] = "Score: " + str(score)

    def test4():
        global score

        if ticket2 == 1:
            button4.config(text="RIP", bg="red")
        else:
            button4.config(text="+2", bg="green")
            score += 1
            label_score['text'] = "Score: " + str(score)

    def test5():
        global score

        if ticket2 == 2:
            button5.config(text="RIP", bg="red")
        else:
            button5.config(text="+2", bg="green")
            score += 1
            label_score['text'] = "Score: " + str(score)

    def test6():
        global score

        if ticket2 == 3:
            button6.config(text="RIP", bg="red")
        else:
            button6.config(text="+2", bg="green")
            score += 1
            label_score['text'] = "Score: " + str(score)


    ticket1 = random.randint(1, 3)
    ticket2 = random.randint(1, 3)

    button1 = tk.Button(screen, text="1", fg="white", bg="blue", width=15, height=2, command=test1)
    button1.grid(row=1, column=0, sticky="w")

    button2 = tk.Button(screen, text="2", fg="white", bg="blue", width=15, height=2, command=test2)
    button2.grid(row=1, column=1, sticky="wens")

    button3 = tk.Button(screen, text="3", fg="white", bg="blue", width=15, height=2, command=test3)
    button3.grid(row=1, column=2, sticky="e")

    button4 = tk.Button(screen, text="1", fg="white", bg="blue", width=15, height=2, command=test4)
    button4.grid(row=0, column=0, sticky="w")

    button5 = tk.Button(screen, text="2", fg="white", bg="blue", width=15, height=2, command=test5)
    button5.grid(row=0, column=1, sticky="wens")

    button6 = tk.Button(screen, text="3", fg="white", bg="blue", width=15, height=2, command=test6)
    button6.grid(row=0, column=2, sticky="e")

# --- main --

score = 0

screen = tk.Tk()

button_start = tk.Button(screen, text="START", fg="black", bg="orange", width=25, height=2, command=test)
button_start.grid(row=8, columnspan=3, sticky="wens")

label_score = tk.Label(screen, text="Score: 0", width=25, height=2)
label_score.grid(row=9, columnspan=3, sticky="wens")

screen.mainloop()
```